# Windows: How do I remove a file's ACL, and just let it inherit the ACL on the containing directory?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, acl

Scenario: I unpack a file into a temp directory.

Then I movve the file into a different directory.  I want the file ACL to *only* include the perms stipulated in the new containing directory.  How can I make that happen?

In UI, and in command line would be good.  icacls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the reset function of icacls:

```
ICACLS "C:\path\to\folder" /reset /T /C
```

then enable inheritance:

```
ICACLS "C:\path\to\folder" /inheritance:e /T /C
```

Comment: On Windows XP, I'm getting `Invalid parameter "/inheritance:e"`, any idea? (I've installed icacls a couple of weeks ago, so I don't think upgrading would help).

Comment: `/inheritance` is not listed as a parameter on the [`icacls` documentation page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx).